# If I learn Codeigniter, can I use it with Drupal or is that a bad idea and I should use Expression Engine?

Tags: php, drupal, codeigniter, frameworks, expressionengine

Will learning Codeigniter (or any framework for that matter such as CakePHP or Zend) help my development in Drupal or are they two separate systems that won't really benefit the other when I have knowledge in one?

I know expression engine is a CMS developed specifically with codeigniter in mind, but Drupal has a larger community and I was hoping I'd still be able to stick with drupal as well and see if me knowing codeigniter (currently what i'm studying, i haven't gotten into drupal yet) will be of any use for developing in drupal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal & CodeIgniter are different PHP frameworks (Drupal could be considered the CMS that became a Framework). Your work/learning in CodeIgniter will undoubtedly give you perspective when working with Drupal and grow your coding skills, but it wont necessarily help you learn Drupal Core API's and Methodologies.

I recommend getting into Drupal cause it's hawt (in demand), once you get your head around assumptions & common patterns it helps you build things very fast, the community is huge and all the cool kids are doing it. But if you are learning CodeIgniter and want to leverage that learning in EE, that makes perfect sense...and if that's what you/your clients want, rock on.

To start with Drupal I recommend getting into what it can do out of the box with Core & Popular Contrib Modules:

http://drupal.org/documentation/structure

Here are a few more learning resources for drupal:

http://drupalize.me  (video site with lotsa free content and fair priced paid content)
http://planet.drupal.org  (the drupal planet feed, lotsa great tutorials come down the pipe)
http://api.drupal.org  (your friendly Core API docs)
http://drupal.org   (excellent multisite search kicks butt for finding help on your topic)

Comment: To find a web developer job better (i'm planning on freelancing), is it better to just specialize either drupal or codeigniter rather than both? Or do most web developers know one framework and one CMS inside out regardless if knowledge in each helps the other? I'm trying to figure out my career path.

Comment: That is a much bigger question :) I would say your not going to hurt for knowledge of CI & Drupal & Node.js for that matter. In time you'll know when an App needs to get off the ground without any CMS assumptions and also when Drupal is perfect...then again in time drupal will just be perfect for everything (jk) ;P

Comment: thanks, then I'll keep on studying CI for now and also get into Drupal afterwards.

Comment: One advantage of drupal is that if you are half way competent you can get work very quickly since it's so popular, and since it's more of a cms you can do small jobs easily and quickly. From a getting work standpoint I'd suggest learning drupal first. From a purely academic standpoint I'd suggest CI.

Answer (score 1):

Both Codeigniter and Drupal is great but Codeigniter and Drupal's structures are different. Learning Codeigniter for Drupal does not sound like a great idea.

Comment: I'm just getting started out and was under the false impression that web developers needed to know at least one framework and one CMS. So just to clarify, it's more like, learn and specialize in either Drupal or Codeigniter, rather than specialize in one CMS (drupal) and one framework (Codeigniter), is this more correct?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use them both, cause you will just waste your time.
Instead, start with CI cause it's easier, find out how the code works, develop some sites or applications and then start with Drupal which is much more complex at least for customizing, but yet more powerful CMS. I haven't tried Expression Engine yet, but it has really nice feedback especially from designers.